# Website Theme for IPhone - What are The Basic Ingredients?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

Has anybody made a website theme for the iPhone?

Please let me know any tips or resources.

Here's my theory: How to make a website theme for iPhone

1. Create a website theme designed for desktop monitors. Try not to make any element larger than 320px (iPhone screen resolution).
2. Create 2 style sheets. One for desktop monitors and another for iPhone. By default, the desktop version of the style sheet is called. The iPhone style sheet would display items in such a way that they fit inside the 320px resolution.
3. Create JavaScript file that detects Screen Size. If screen size is less than than 321px, then the style sheet is replaced by the iPhone version style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Liquid layouts work well. When you switch from landscape to portrait and back on the iPhone, text reflows. [I've used this one.](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts)

Comment: Great example. I'm trying to make something a bit different though. I would like to use a multi column layout for desktop and single column for iPhone

Comment: Have you looked at iUi and jQTouch?

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking to apply the theme to an existing CMS, so those seem a little overkill. I can probably borrow some CSS though...

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[IUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/)** which provides a very iPhone like UI for your website/application. (Free!)

Examples:

- [Music Layout](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/music.html)
- [Digg-like layout](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/digg/index.html)

Comment: IUI looks awesome, but I'm not sure it will fit my requirements. Also, there is very little documentation. I'm trying to make a theme for an ecommerce website that will display differently on iPhone vs desktop.

Comment: no worries just figured if you want a base for the iPhone styles this might help.